# How to use implode with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to combine a search bar with checkboxes for a query in PDO.

The current code is like this:

```
$keywordfromform = $_GET["keyword"];
$keyword = "%$keywordfromform%";

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table
        WHERE column1 LIKE ?
           OR column2 LIKE ?
           OR column3 LIKE ?
           ORDER BY column3 ASC';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($keyword, $keyword, $keyword);
$entries = $stmt->fetchAll();
$count = count($entries);
```

With the same logic, I tried to apply implode and the in-clause as follows (according to [this site](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in)):

```
//search bar
$keywordfromform = $_GET["keyword"];
$keyword = "%$keywordfromform%";

//checkboxes
$column1 = $_GET['checkboxes_column1'];
$implode_column1 = implode(', ', $column1);
$in str_repeat('?,', count($implode_column1) - 1) . '?';


$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table
        WHERE column1 LIKE ?
           OR column2 LIKE ?
           OR column3 LIKE ?
          AND column1 IN ($in)
        ORDER BY column3 ASC';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$params = array_merge([$keyword], [$keyword], [$keyword], $implode_column1);
$stmt->execute($params);
$entries = $stmt->fetchAll();
$count = count($entries);
```

The search bar and checkboxes are standard ones from bootstrap, nothing special.

Maybe someone could kindly point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$in str_repeat()` looks suspect. Perhaps you meant to put an equal sign for assignment there.

Comment: In addition to that, when you use a single quote char for defining a string, as you do for `$sql`, it will not reference your vars.

Comment: When mixing AND's and OR's in a WHERE clause it is always advisable to use brackets to ensure the correct result `WHERE column 1 IN ($in) and (column1 LIKE ? OR column2 LIKE ?  OR column3 LIKE ?)` at a guess

Comment: Also `column 1` look wrong, with a space between `n` and `1`

Comment: But of course if you told us what the problem was, we could probably be more specific

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Column1 was not the probem. I'm currently trying the brackets and the `$in str_repeat()`, but having hard times especially with the latter.

Comment: Should be `$in = str_repeat(`. But you also have other issues. Am surprised you didnt follow the syntax error reported on this.

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: But the link exactly says `$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';` and I only switched out `$arr` with the implode cause.

Comment: I have `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in it. Sorry for my really noob question, but why are you talking about MYSQLI_errors when I am using PDO? I'm getting confused, sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problems

1. `$sql` uses single quotes not double; therefore `$in` is literal
2. `count($implode_column1)` isn't countable; it's a string
3. `$in str_repeat(...)` - as per the comments - needs an assignment operator
4. `array_merge(...)` doesn't work; `$implode_column1` is a string
5. **Assumption** you need parenthesis to specify order of operation assuming that the `ORs` should be grouped together:

   ```
   (a = ... OR b = ... OR c = ...) AND a IN (...)
   ```

### Incoming data

Assuming that your incoming data is in the format:

```
$_GET['keyword']            = "html";
$_GET['checkboxes_column1'] = [
                                0 => "php",
                                1 => "css",
                                2 => "js",
                                3 => "html"
                              ];
```

### Updated code

```
$keyword = $_GET['keyword']            ?? NULL;
$column1 = $_GET['checkboxes_column1'] ?? NULL;

// Check that the expected data was received
if(!$column1 || !$keyword || !is_array($column1)){
    echo "Error: Nothing submitted";
    exit;
}

$keyword      = "%{$keyword}%";
$placeholders = implode(", ", array_fill(0, count($column1), "?"));    // Prepare placeholder string
$parameters   = array_merge([$keyword, $keyword, $keyword], $column1); // Prepare array for variables to bind

$sql    = "
    SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE (
            column1 LIKE ?
        OR  column2 LIKE ?
        OR  column3 LIKE ?
      ) AND column1 IN   ({$placeholders})
    ORDER BY column3 ASC
";

$query  = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($parameters);
$result = $query->fetchAll();
$count  = count($result);
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so so much for your effort and especially for explaining me the problems carefully, that helps a lot!